# wake laptop over hdmi from tv?

Tags: ubuntu, hdmi, sleep, kodi, wake-up

I have XBMC setup on my laptop, which is connected to my tv via an HDMI cable. On the laptop I am running ubuntu 13.10.

Would it be possible to have my laptop sleep and wake depending on whether the tv is on or off?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does both your TV and laptop support [HDMI-CEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#CEC)? if not, this will not work.

Comment: Im afraid im not sure. How would I find this out?

Comment: Most HDMI ports on computers won't support HDMI-CEC out of the box. A lot of people will buy a [Pulse Eight CEC adapter](http://www.pulse-eight.com/store/products/104-usb-hdmi-cec-adapter.aspx) to add that functionality. A lot of TVs have this functionality but they brand it as VieraLink (Panasonic), Aquos Link (Sharp), etc.